# Eclipse PyDev is throwing false errors

Tags: eclipse, ide, pydev

I updated PyDev (Eclipse) yesterday and now it is telling me that None, **name** and other reserved words/builtin functions are invalid, but the script runs just fine. I have read on this forum that the problem deals with incorrectly importing the built-ins. I have tried changing the interpreter and re-adding it but no luck. Can somebody help me please?

The errors:

Undefined variable **main**
Undefined variable None
Undefined variable int
Undefined variable eval

I am running eclipse Juno and PyDev 2.7.4. also, I notice that the errors only appear after the PyDev code analysis ends.

Comment: A little update: I downgraded to PyDev 2.6 and this problem does not happen. I upgraded to the nightly build, PyDev 2.7.5, and no luck either. Looks like something changed from 2.7 onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I see nobody has come up with some idea. I found out by myself so I'm posting how I solved it here; maybe it'll help somebody:

The problem was that I had recently changed my local machine's name, but PyDev was still looking for localhost when it tried to connect to the Python Shell. I just updated the files in my operating system containing the hostname, and voila (the automatic wizard did not update all the files for some reason, so I had to do it manually).

Comment: This has happened to me recently... Do you think you could post the steps?

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me as well, the problem was that eclipse couldn't find python.

My fix:

in Eclipse:

Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - Python

The settings here were blank.  I clicked 'Auto Config', which suggested to me the path to python.  I chose it, restarted eclipse, and problem solved.