# Error in Eclipse IDE(Pydev) on built-in max() function, and other built-ins if error is commented out

Tags: python, linux, ide, editor, built-in

I'm getting these errors in Pydev on built-ins, what is wrong here and to remedy this?

Here it is:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I've looked at this, but it doesn't seem to be related:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696792/eclipse-pydev-is-throwing-false-errors)

Comment: Is it possible that pydev is using the python 3.*, but that you're writing python 2.*? At least that's what the error message seems to suggest.

Comment: @Dunes Ok that sounds like it could be the case, your right it was set to 3. I'm still learning and a newbie, but it doesn't matter if I change the interpreter to 2.7 or 2.4 the error is still there.

Comment: When you said you changed the interpreter, how did you do that? It might be that PyDev has different program versus project settings. Additionally, Eclipse might require a restart after the change. I can't really comment much more as I use PyCharm rather than PyDev.

Comment: @Dunes Thank's for attention, I have restarted since before, after I changed the interpreter to 2.7 and now the errors are gone. So that was probably the case. I changed the interpreter in Project -> Properties -> PyDev - Interpreter/Grammer and changed the grammer version to 2.7. If you want to write up an answer that would be great, then I accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the interpreter from `python 3` to `python 2.7`, I did this by: In eclipse the options are:`Project -> Properties -> PyDev - Interpreter/Grammer` and changed the grammer version to `2.7`, then I restarted the computer(probably enough to restart eclipse), and the problem is fixed.

Sorry about the noobness