# None, False, True reported as undefined variables

Tags: pydev

I am using PyDev 3.0.0 (Eclipse 4.4.1). After an update a few days ago, PyDev is reporting "Undefined variable" one a large number of keywords, most notably `None`, `True` and `False`; errors are being reported on 30-40% lines of code in all projects. However, all projects and scripts can be run from Eclipse without issue.

In Juno there was [an issue with similar symptoms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696792/eclipse-pydev-is-throwing-false-errors) caused by an interpreter misconfiguration. But in Luna these false errors are being reported with the interpreter auto-configured. I have tried switching between the 2.7 and 3.4 interpreters, but these errors remain.

**Update I**: the precise versions reported at the *About Eclipse* menu:

Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800

Feature Name: Pydev - Python Development
Version: 3.0.0.201406111920-7v777uVyx2EKHY

**Update II**: this is now [bug #549 at the PyDev bug tracker](https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/549).

Comment: PyDev 3.0.0 doesn't use Eclipse 4.4.1. Could you please provide your exact version? http://pydev.org/history_pydev.html

Comment: Maybe you should [file a bugreport](http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F), if you are having troubles after updating.